# Excel VBA create report with grouped values

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a report in Excel using VBA to process some data and create a tabular report that summarizes the values by group.  Although I can generate the table manually, I can't get the code to fully create this report.

Input data:

```
ID | name   | number | class | comment
---|--------|--------|-------|----------       
 1 | john   |      4 | A1    | sports
---|--------|--------|-------|----------      
 1 | john   |      3 | A2    | sports
---|--------|--------|-------|----------      
 1 | john   |      5 | A3    | sports
---|--------|--------|-------|----------      
 2 | charly |      1 | B3    | tech
---|--------|--------|-------|----------     
 2 | charly |      2 | B2    | tech
---|--------|--------|-------|----------  
 2 | charly |      1 | B2    | tech
---|--------|--------|-------|----------   
 3 | frank  |      7 | C3    | language
---|--------|--------|-------|----------     
 3 | frank  |      2 | C5    | language
---|--------|--------|-------|----------  
 3 | frank  |      9 | C4    | language
```

Expected summary in a new worksheet:

```
ID | name   | number  | class      | comment
---|--------|---------|------------|----------
 1 | john   | ”3,4,5” | ”A1,A2,A3” | sports
---|--------|---------|------------|----------
 2 | charly | ”1,2”   | ”B2,B3”    | tech
---|--------|---------|------------|----------
 3 | frank  | ”2,7,9” | ”C3,C4,C5” | language
```

Here is the code I currently have:

```
Function Uniques(r As Range)

Dim d As Object, c As Range, tmp
     Set d = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
     For Each c In rCells
        tmp = Trim(c.Value)
        If Len(tmp) > 0 Then
             If Not d.Exists(tmp) And tmp <> “HEADER” Then d.Add tmp, 1
        End If
     Next c
     Uniques = d.keysEnd Function
     With .Range("A1:N" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
           .AutoFilter Field:=1
           Set a = .Columns(“A”).Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
           Set b = .Columns(“B”).Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
           'getting the unique items
            d = Uniques(Range("D:D").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))
           .AutoFilter
     End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach to use dictionary is a step in the right direction though it needs 1 more of that dictionary object to use it in the sub loops. It gets a bit complex and interesting due to additional columns and the requirements of unique and sorted data as indicated under the expected summary portion in the question.

The below updated code assumes that the macro is triggered from the sheet containing this data and generates the output in Sheet(2):

```
Sub strSplit()
    Dim r As Range, lastRow As Long, k As Variant, k1 As Variant, d As Object, d1 As Object, i As Long, j As Long, cmnt As String
    Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set d1 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For Each r In Range("B2:B" & lastRow)
        If Not IsEmpty(r) Then d(r.Value) = r.Offset(0, -1).Value
    Next
    For Each k In d.Keys
        i = i + 1
        Sheets(2).Cells(i + 1, 1) = d(k)
        Sheets(2).Cells(i + 1, 2) = k

        'get list of unique numbers for each ID + comment
        For Each r In Range("B2:B" & lastRow)
            If k = r.Value Then
                d1(r.Offset(0, 1).Value) = r.Value
                cmnt = r.Offset(0, 3).Value
            End If
        Next
        j = 0
        For Each k1 In d1.Keys
            If j = 0 Then Sheets(2).Cells(i + 1, 5) = cmnt
            Sheets(2).Cells(j + d.Count + 2, 3) = k1
            j = j + 1
        Next
        Set r = Sheets(2).Range("C" & d.Count + 2 & ":C" & j + 1 + d.Count)
        r.Sort r.Columns(1)
        Sheets(2).Cells(i + 1, 3) = colToRw(r)
        r.ClearContents
        d1.RemoveAll

        'get list of unique classes for each ID
        For Each r In Range("B2:B" & lastRow)
            If k = r.Value Then d1(r.Offset(0, 2).Value) = r.Value
        Next
        j = 0
        For Each k1 In d1.Keys
            Sheets(2).Cells(j + d.Count + 2, 4) = k1
            j = j + 1
        Next
        Set r = Sheets(2).Range("D" & d.Count + 2 & ":D" & j + 1 + d.Count)
        r.Sort r.Columns(1)
        Sheets(2).Cells(i + 1, 4) = colToRw(r)
        r.ClearContents
        d1.RemoveAll
    Next
    Sheets(2).Select
End Sub
Function colToRw(r As Range) As String
    Dim r1 As Range, is1st As Boolean
    is1st = True
    For Each r1 In r
        If Not is1st Then
            colToRw = colToRw & ", "
        Else: is1st = False
        End If
        colToRw = colToRw & r1.Value
    Next
End Function
```

**2<sup>nd</sup> version:**

Based on subsequent discussion, here's a modified and leaner version with a more functional approach. Under this approach, the column that needs to be searched for an ordered and unique list, can be set in the functional call.

```
Sub strSplit()
    Dim r As Range, lastRow As Long, rng As Range, k As Variant, d As Object, i As Long
    Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = Range("B2:B" & lastRow)
    For Each r In rng
        If Not IsEmpty(r) Then d(r.Value) = r.Offset(0, -1).Value
    Next
    For Each k In d.Keys
        i = i + 1
        Sheets(2).Cells(i + 1, 1) = d(k) 'column 1
        Sheets(2).Cells(i + 1, 2) = k 'column 2
        For Each r In rng
            If k = r.Value Then
                Sheets(2).Cells(i + 1, 5) = r.Offset(0, 3).Value 'column 5
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        Sheets(2).Cells(i + 1, 3) = uniqNsort(k, rng, 1, d.Count) 'column 3
        Sheets(2).Cells(i + 1, 4) = uniqNsort(k, rng, 2, d.Count) 'column 4
    Next
    Sheets(2).Select
End Sub
Function uniqNsort(k, rng As Range, rngOffsetCol As Long, rwNo As Long) As String 'get ordered list of unique items
    Dim k1, r As Range, i As Long, d As Object
    Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For Each r In rng
        If k = r.Value Then
            d(r.Offset(0, rngOffsetCol).Value) = r.Value
        End If
    Next
    For Each k1 In d.Keys
        Sheets(2).Cells(i + rwNo + 2, 1) = k1
        i = i + 1
    Next
    Set r = Sheets(2).Range("A" & rwNo + 2 & ":A" & rwNo + i + 1)
    r.Sort r.Columns(1)
    uniqNsort = colToRw(r)
    r.ClearContents
End Function
Function colToRw(r As Range) As String
    Dim r1 As Range, is1st As Boolean
    is1st = True
    For Each r1 In r
        If Not is1st Then
            colToRw = colToRw & ", "
        Else: is1st = False
        End If
        colToRw = colToRw & r1.Value
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: It works but sometimes the column C "number" doesn't get written properly next to its "name" and its been added alone as new line at the end. is it possible to point out where are the COLUMN variables i need to change in the event I need to add more columns and still use this function? thank you

Comment: try now? i hv simplified col C to `Sheets(2).Cells(i + 1, 3) = colToRw(r)` & col D to `Sheets(2).Cells(i + 1, 4) = colToRw(r)`.  other columns are: col A = `Sheets(2).Cells(i + 1, 1) = d(k)`, col B = `Sheets(2).Cells(i + 1, 2) = k`, & col E = `If j = 0 Then Sheets(2).Cells(i + 1, 5) = cmnt`

Comment: thank you. It works. I am now just having issues to update column C to column H,  when I change it it throws an error in the r.Sort r.Columns(1) "Sort Method of Range class failed". the column H has numbers just as column C shown in the example table. should I change any other value to make it work using column H instead of C? it populates only ",,,,,," r seems to be blank. I've marked your answer as the solution. thank you.

Comment: u are welcome. as u need other additional columns to be processed in the same way, i have added a 2nd version where u may mention the column#. e.g. `Sheets(2).Cells(i + 1, 3) = uniqNsort(k, rng, 1, d.Count)` for column C and `Sheets(2).Cells(i + 1, 4) = uniqNsort(k, rng, 2, d.Count)` for column D, & so on. note we only need to change in 2 places

Comment: where are those two places?

Comment: 2 places in the example i mentioned in the last comment, i.e. "`Sheets(2).Cells(i + 1, 3) = uniqNsort(k, rng, 1, d.Count)` for column C and `Sheets(2).Cells(i + 1, 4) = uniqNsort(k, rng, 2, d.Count)` for column D, & so on". as u can see the only 2 values changed - (1) 3 changed to 4 in `Cells(i + 1, 3)` because of col D, (2) 1 changed to 2 in `uniqNsort(k, rng, 1, d.Count)`  because col C is offset 1 to the right & col D is offset 2 to the right of the main range of col B